# jQuery: hide div on hover, stay visible on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple of `position: absolute;` "buttons" `display:block;` `<a>`'s and a couple of `position: absolute;` div's with text in them. The div's are hidden by `display:none;` set to the default.

When you **hover**hover over a button, the div next to it (in the code) should appear (with some kind of fade/scroll effect) and then fade/scroll out again if you move the cursor away from the button.

When you **click** on a button, the div next to it should stay visible (i.e. display:block;). It should only disappear again if you click on the button or the div itself (hovering over the button or the div shouldn't change anything).

I thought this would be straightforward, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

with a little knowledge of your html, here's how I got it.

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="mybutton">button</a>
<div class="mydiv">some text in it.</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.mydiv').addClass('hover').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('hover').fadeOut();
});

$('a.mybutton').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').toggleClass('hover').show();
    // $('.mydiv').removeClass('hover').show();
}).hover(function() {
    $('.mydiv.hover').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('.mydiv.hover').fadeOut();
});
```

## [Crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/HtYsQ/1/)

Comment: Great! Could you, if possible, also make the `<div>` disappear if it's being clicked on (after it has been enabled by clicking on the button of course)? Thanks!

Comment: What is that again? I did not quite get it. sorry I'm not an English person :)

Comment: Let's say you clicked on the button. The `<div>` will now be visible. I want to be able to hide it again by either clicking on the button again (this already works in your example) or by clicking on the `<div>` itself (that's what's missing). Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Now it only closes if you click on the `<div>`. I guess it won't work with both the button and the `<div>`? Like a combination of your first and this demo. Thanks!

Comment: `Now it only closes if you click on the <div>` - really?

Comment: EDIT: it closes if I click on the button too, but only after I've moved away from the button after the click. So if I click on the button to show the `<div>` and then click on the button again to hide it again, it does nothing UNTIL I move the cursor away from the button. Sounds like a minor bug, maybe you can figure it out? Would be great! Thanks!

Comment: this,`When you hover over a button, the <div> next to it (in the code) should appear`, explains that?

Comment: Is there no way to have it behave differently when the `<div>` is visible?