# JQuery - Click to keep a div displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when a div `.TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent` is clicked, I want `.div-TQA-SF006-U-160` to be displayed always and `.div-TQA-SF006-U-static` to be hidden **after mouseout function is executed.**

Any help would be appreciated.

[JSFiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpk82w65/3/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: hide div on hover, stay visible on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273560/jquery-hide-div-on-hover-stay-visible-on-click)

Comment: I clearly mentioned that my problem was occurring after mouseout function is executed which I can't find solution to in that post you linked. I don't see how it is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a class to track the state of the element you're hovering/clicking, and only use the mouseover/mouseout code if the state is not clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $parent = $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent"),
    $static = $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static"),
    $160 = $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160");

  $parent.on('mouseover', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      $static.addClass('hide');
      $160.addClass('show');
    }
  }).on('mouseout', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      $static.removeClass('hide');
      $160.removeClass('show');
    }
  }).on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $static.addClass('hide');
    $160.addClass('show');
  });

});
```

```css
.div-TQA-SF006 .td-suspension-child-row2:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.table-suspension-list {
  border: 0;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber {
  border: 1px solid #1F497D;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #1F497D;
  color: white;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber-bottom {
  border: 1px solid #1F497D;
  background-color: #1F497D;
  color: white;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber div {
  color: white;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber-bottom div {
  color: white;
}

.table-suspension-list .partDescription {
  border: 1px solid #1F497D;
  color: #1F497D;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-suspension-list .partDescription div {
  color: #1F497D;
}

.table-suspension tbody {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #002060;
}

.table-suspension th {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #002060;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #002060;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.td-suspension-parent {
  background-color: #deeaf6;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.td-suspension-child {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.td-suspension-child-row2 {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.td-suspension-child div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.td-suspension-child-row2 div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.div-TQA-SF006-U-160 {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-TQA-SF006">
  <table class="table-suspension">
    <tbody>
      <th colspan="6">
        SPECIFICATIONS
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent" colspan="3" style="width: 50%">Part Number</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent" colspan="3" style="width: 50%">Description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-child" colspan="3">TQA-SF006</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child" colspan="3">Underslung Air Suspension for 10 Ton Axle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent" colspan="6">Available Ride Height</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent">160mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-200mm-parent">200mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-250mm-parent">250mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-275mm-parent">275mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-300mm-parent">300mm</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

&nbsp;

<div class="div-TQA-SF006-U-static">
  <table class="table-suspension">
    <tbody>
      <th>
        Spare Parts
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">Hover mouse over desired Ride Height for pop-up information</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="div-TQA-SF006-U-160">
  <table class="table-suspension">
    <tbody>
      <th colspan="6">
        SPARE PARTS
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-SPA07</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-PB006</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-AB08</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-SA08</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-UB001</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-SPA20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Parabolic Spring Straight Type</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Pivot Bolt Kit</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Air Spring</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Shock Absorber</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">U-Bot Kit</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Spring Bush</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can anyone explain the downvote and why my answer "is not useful"?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I can't anyway due to lack of reputation. Someone has downvoted all posts on this page.

Comment: I actually just used your code on my other pages that worked well too. Thanks for both the solution and kindly given upvote.

Comment: @JulySFX sweet, you're welcome! Glad it helped :)

Comment: [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv0art72/1/)
I just added the exact same JSQuery code block for spare parts information of 200mm. As soon as I click 160mm and click 200mm, `.div-TQA-SF006-U-static` shows while `.div-TQA-SF006-U-160` stays displayed. Any possible solution to this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

one easy way to do this is to add a global variable to check, whether that div condition is `clicked` or not. Then, you execute `mouseover` and `mouseout` event, when that div is not clicked

```
  var clicked = false;
    $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").on('mouseover',function(){
    if (clicked == false){
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").hide();
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").show();
    }
  }); 
  $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").on('mouseout', function(){
    if (clicked == false){
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").show();
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").hide();
    }
  });
  $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").click(function(){
    if (clicked == false){
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").hide();
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").show();
      clicked = true;
    }
    else{
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").show();
      $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").hide();
      clicked = false;
    }
  });
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xpk82w65/4/

Also, you can attach binding to same elements, without re-calling those elements.
for example :

```
  $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").on('mouseover',function(){
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(){
  })
  .on('click', function(){
  });
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xpk82w65/6/

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.